# Если два столбца из двух разных файлов равны, заменить третий столбец с awk

Tags: awk

Файл `а.txt`:

```
SNP CHR POS EFFECT_ALLELE   NON_EFFECT_ALLELE   EAF BETA    SE  PVALUE  INFO    HWE
chr:1:10177:AC:A    1   10177   A   AC  0.376827    -0.0447626  0.0316126   0.156783    0.422784    0.936182
chr:1:10352:TA:T    1   10352   T   TA  0.00727013  0.0309617   0.814356    0.427932    0.680802
```

Некоторые строки файла `а.txt` не имеют `$6`
Файл `b.txt`

```
10177 0.376827
10352 0.43176
```

Я ищу как можно заменить `$6` столбцом `$2` из `b.txt`
Спасибо за любую помощь

Comment: А чем поля в файле разделены ?

Comment: Если табуляцией, то что то вроде `awk -F $'\t' '$6 {print $3,$6} !$6 {print $3,$2}'`

Comment: Да табуляцией. Точнее результат выглядит вот так `POS EAF
10177 0.376827
10352 0.43176`. Только 2 столбца

Comment: так вы попробуйте что я предложил, должно работать

Comment: хотя я не понял, откуда у вас 0.43176 взялось, в входном файле такого значения нет

Comment: я попробовала, результат это 2 столбца `POS ` и `EAF `.  0.43176 во втором столбце, 2 строка файла b.txt

Comment: в приведенном вами образце входного файла во втором столбце 1. А значение 0.43176 там вообще не встречается